# cqlsh command line can't be opened in Apache Cassandra

Tags: shell, cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I have installed Cassandra by following this tutorial: [here](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted#fnref-cac370d9c0a5bbfcc8ba5b7e5a5e742501e0181d). 
In the `bin` directory, there is cqlsh, that I am supposed to open to write command in order to create Table, Column etc..

But the `cqlsh` executable file isn't opening. If I click it, a pop up windows (looks like a shell) appears and quickly disappears. Where is my error and how can enable this file to open?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it sounds like you're running on Windows.  Cassandra support for Windows is still a very new "thing," so honestly I would stick to your favorite flavor of Linux, IMO.

Secondly, what's happening is that you are running `cqlsh` without specifying an IP address or any other parameters that you might need.  If you just want to run it on your local machine, open up a CMD window, and run (assuming that your local Python is properly pathed):

```
c:> python.exe cqlsh <IP_Address>
```

Have you turned on authentication and authorization?  If so, you'll have to add it to that command as well:

```
c:> python.exe cqlsh <IP_Address> -u cassandra -p cassandra
```